# Binding Vue v-model with initial data coming from server side

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue and I am trying to understand some concepts. So I have a website that is a mix of server-side and front-end rendering. When the index is first loaded it will return the first 10 products which are rendered by the server-side. Then the user will use a search filter to search for specific products or just scroll down so more products are loaded. This searching and loading will be done by Vue. Now the question is how to bind the data that is rendered initially by the server with the current `data` object of Vue?

The [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#basic-usage) says

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes
> found on any form elements. **It will always treat the current active
> instance data as the source of truth**. You should declare the initial
> value on the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your
> component.

So one can load the index without any data, then fire a second request to load the initial data but why waste one HTTP request on that?

Comment: This one request doesn't matter, better way is to fetch this data from server

Comment: @BartoszKarwacki why it doesn't matter?

Comment: What is your backend? How do you use Vue? I mean, is it just included on the page and loaded from CDN + template is directly in server side rendered HTML ? Show some code...

Comment: The cost of one request is just small, vue fetchs a lot of data anyway. The first 10 products gonna be the same whole time? If you like to make any changes in the future, you would do that twice

Comment: OK, let me close this question until I get some code and the images maybe.

Comment: The question is well formulated - just missing some detailed info. No need to close - just edit and add more info...